# Record video of any application installed/running in android

Tags: android, video-capture, tablet, audio-recording, smartphone

Android Smartphone/Tablet (2.3 and above): How can I capture a video and audio of an application? I need to record and save movie of my running application.

I know about DDMS, but it takes only screen shots. But I need video + audio being played in android app

Requirement: Need to make video of application installed in android smartphone/tablet. (i.e. capturing screens and voices appearing in the app), something like [screencast](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ms.screencast&hl=en)

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: as per comments on screen cast play store link it "Works fine on my Sony Xperia Sola. Thanks you! It doesn't capture screens from surface Views. (i.e. when enabling the camera/video) It also didn't capture the screen if i was using GOLauncher." .. so it also have its limitation.. and it only works on rooted phones..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use android screencast tools to mirror my android device on my pc.

[Android Screencast](https://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast)

[Droid @ screen](http://droid-at-screen.ribomation.com/)

and a screen recording tool to record screens.

e.g. on macbook i use quicktime player's screen recorder.

[CamStudio for windows](http://camstudio.org)

Comment: what about the quality of audio and video using this approach?